# What does “Krach” mean in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, german-to-english, noun

What does the following sentence mean?

> Ich habe zu Hause Krach.

It was used as an example displaying the meaning of *Krach*, along with the following sentence meaning “I am in trouble with my parents.”

> Ich habe Krach mit meinen Eltern.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=krach&=DEEN&=

Answer (score 9):

It means that you are angry at/have trouble with your partner/parents etc.

Answer (score 4):

*Krach* is a synonym to *Streit*. The meaning comes from **yelling loudly** at each other. Other synonyms:

- *Zoff* (an issue with a bad ending),
- *Ärger* (does not imply a confrontation tho),
- *Stunk* (verb is *stänkern*)
- *dicke Luft* (metaphorical atmosphere)

Answer (score -1):

Usually "Krach" means that you aren't in much trouble.
"Krach" is equal to "Streit"

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Note that we generally prefer answers that explain and give context. Feel free to [edit] your answer if you want to add such content. Learn more about editing and the site in the [help].

Comment: "Wieso bist Du zuhause abgehauen?" - "Ich habe Krach mit meinen Eltern." - dass Krach für wenig Probleme steht würde ich nicht unterschreiben.